# PDF attachment shows garbled text when opened

Tags: pdf

When I open PDF files on my desk, I get....

```
%PDF-1.3
%âãÏÓ

1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R
/Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Outlines
/Count 0
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
/Kids [ 4 0 R ] 
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 3 0 R
/Resources <<
/Font <<
/F1 7 0 R 
/F2 8 0 R 
>>
/ProcSet 6 0 R
>>
/MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
/Contents 5 0 R
>>
endobj

5 0 obj
<< /Length 4079 >>
stream
2 J
BT
0 0 0 rg
/F1 10.08 Tf
218.9165 746.9280 Td
(Sky Bird Travel & Tours of Canada Inc.)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
262.8854 735.5280 Td
(1111 Finch Avenue)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
285.0110 724.1280 Td
(Suite 308)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
246.9086 712.7280 Td
(Toronto, Ontario  M3J 2E5)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
36.0000 682.1280 Td
(Davinder Gill)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
36.0000 670.7280 Td
(GLOBE-TIME TRAVEL LTD)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
36.0000 659.3280 Td
(9718 128A Street )Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
36.0000 647.9280 Td
(Surrey BC   V3T 3C9  )Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
36.0000 636.5280 Td
(Phone:  +1 \(604\) 930-5200)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
36.0000 625.1280 Td
(Fax:  +1 \(604\) 398-2371)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
36.0000 613.7280 Td
(EMail:  davinder@globetimetravel.ca)Tj
ET
BT
/F2 12.00 Tf
258.9480 693.6000 Td
(Client Statement)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
508.2019 669.5280 Td
(To: 11/24/2013)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
475.7040 653.9280 Td
(Client ID: 6049305200)Tj
ET
BT
/F1 10.08 Tf
506.5286 642.5280 Td
(Client No: 1218)Tj
ET
[] 0 d
0 0 0 RG
0.8 0.8 0.8 rg
0.2400 w 
36.0000 600.8400 72.0000 -12.0960 re f
BT
0 0 0 rg
/F1 7.92 Tf
39.6000 590.9040 Td
(Issue Dt)Tj
ET
0 0 0 RG
0.8 0.8 0.8 rg
108.0000 600.8400 72.0000 -12.0960 re f
BT
0 0 0 rg
/F1 7.92 Tf
138.9859 590.9040 Td
(Invoice No)Tj
ET
0 0 0 RG
0.8 0.8 0.8 rg
180.0000 600.8400 396.0000 -12.0960 re f
36.0000 589.2240 18.0000 -9.5040 re f
54.0000 589.2240 72.0000 -9.5040 re f
BT
0 0 0 rg
/F1 7.92 Tf
57.6000 581.4000 Td
(Ticket No)Tj
```

what happened? How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a PDF... I am guessing you have the wrong file association set, so the PDF is opening in a text editor.  Right click the PDF, hit "Open With", select "Adobe Reader" and make sure to check the "Always use the selected program..." option.

If you do not see Adobe Reader as an option, or this procedure does not work, reinstall Adobe Reader from http://adobe.com

Comment: but when I do so, after open option, Adobe reader doesn't come up, a small box comes up, on the top it says File conversion .PDF, I select Windows(default), in the white box below, in preview I see the garbled text. What do I do?

Comment: oh Ok, will uninstall Adobe then re-install it. Thanks will try this option.